# Is there an app that allows me to set music as an alarm?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ipod-touch, alarm

Let me preface this by saying that I am *not* looking to set music in the built-in iOS Clock app. I have tried that and I had problems with it. I usually keep all sounds muted, so it won't work. I also tried [Alarm Clock HD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-hd-free/id476555713?mt=8), which plays music as an alarm but it won't work for me as I needed to be running in the background. I am also using an iPod touch, so [bmike's suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/is-there-an-app-that-allows-me-to-set-music-as-an-alarm#comment82564_71108) isn't feasible.
Here's what I'm looking for: an app that will allow me to a set a song for an alarm and will play that song even if the app is in the background. Alarm Clock HD also had a nice volume feature, which automatically turned up the volume all the way (which is really nice). Is there an iOS app that will do this?

Comment: Arrange a callback service and a custom ringtone so that you can get a wake up call perhaps?

Comment: Oops, sorry @bmike this is an iPod touch...

Comment: Edit the question a bit - list the device. Also, it's not clear what free app you tried - why not link to it or just use it. I think there are several details you didn't convey in writing on this question.

Comment: What problems did you have with the built in clock app

Comment: @markhunte Read the first paragraph in my question

Comment: That does not really explain. i can have my mute button on and still pick a song for an alarm. Which will play with mute. If it is the mute you think is the issue how are you and what are you muting?

Comment: @markhunte "iPod touch" not an iPhone.

Comment: Ok. I missed that. But from the apple doc http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204019 "You'll still hear clock alarms through the built-in speaker when your device is set to silent. You can also use Do Not Disturb to silence calls, alerts, and notifications.", --- "  on the  iPod touch
Pressing and holding the Volume Down button." Will silence everything. So what I am trying to understand is how you are muting and what is actually happening. Knowing this would help in knowing if anything should or would work. If you feel like expanding on this please add it to the answer.

Comment: @markhunte That's exactly what I'm doing. I'm muting it by pressing the Vol Down to mute the ringer

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8, the native Clock app supports selecting your own music. When selecting a sound, choose "Pick a song" at the top. Presto!

Comment: Im am sure it did that before iOS 8

Answer (score 0):

I use [Alarmed](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarmed-reminders-timers-alarm/id371886784?mt=8) and it can have any file in the music library set as an alarm.  Unfortunately I think you have to pay for the "full" version ($2 USD) to access that feature, otherwise you have to use the included audio files. It's worth noting that I bought the full version simply because I liked the application so much—it's easily one of the top three most used apps on my iPod Touch.

It does behave differently if you leave it running in the background, but it still works for me (iOS 5 and later).

Comment: So even if it's still in the background, it still turns on the music?

Comment: I just tested it (I've never used that particular feature). Unfortunately it appears that it will not play from your iTunes library unless it is in the foreground; it just plays its default sound when the alarm triggers and the app is in the background.

Comment: Okay...This may just be a limitation of iOS, but I really want it to be able to play in the background (so I don't have to open up the app before I go to bed at night, nor do I have to turn off Do Not Disturb, which will wake me up with incoming emails)

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation to Alarmed correctly, this is indeed an iOS limitation.  At least Alarmed still makes _some_ kind of alert sound even if it's in the background.  It has worked well for me as an alarm clock. I use its other features too; timers, to-do list reminders, etc.

Comment: You can set do not disturb to a schedual and have it turn off a minute before you alarm.